# $(U\circ T)^{*} = T^{*}\circ U^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $T : V \longrightarrow W$ and $U : W \longrightarrow Z$ be linear maps. How do I prove that $(U\circ T)^{*} = T^{*}\circ U^{*}$? I'm used to seeing $V^{*}$ not $(U\circ T)^{*}$. Any help is appreciated.

$^{*}$ denotes the dual map (transpose).

[image]

Comment: Does $*$ denote the adjoint of the operator?

Comment: I suspect so. I've never heard of that, but I saw it in the indices of Friedberg, Artin, Hoffman, Axler, Halmos, Vinberg, Gockenbach, and Cohn.

Comment: Check this out then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint

Comment: ...[checking]...

Comment: Hermitian adjoint won't work in this case because $V\neq W$ and $W\neq Z$. You need something more general like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Transpose_of_linear_maps

Comment: ...[checking]...

Comment: What is the simplest definition of $T^{*}$?

Comment: @Yosef: In what context did you see $T^*$ written?  In what context are you "used to" seeing $V^*$?

Comment: As the dual space ($V^{*}$). What is a bilinear form?

Comment: What do you want to denote by $T^\ast$? The questions as stated is meaningles until you tell us what you want to denote using $T^\ast$.

Comment: The dual map! ^_^

Comment: Maybe you want to show first your own effort.

Comment: In Artin's *Algebra* I find that "the rules for computing with adjoint matrices carry over to adjoint operators."

Comment: $(U\circ T)^*(\phi)=\phi\circ (U\circ T)=(\phi\circ U)\circ T=T^*(\phi\circ U)=\ldots$

Comment: No, $T^{*}$ is the transpose of $T$. Not the adjoint.

Comment: Yes, [the transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Transpose_of_a_linear_map). This is a straightforward exercise on the associativity of composition. Which I almost completed above, leaving you with the last step.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following data:

\begin{array}{lcl}
T:V\rightarrow W & \leadsto & T^*:W^*\rightarrow V^* \\
U:W\rightarrow Z & \leadsto & U^*:Z^*\rightarrow W^* \\
UT:V\rightarrow Z & \leadsto & \color{red}{(UT)^*:Z^*\rightarrow W^*} \\ \\
 & \Downarrow & \\
\\
V\overset{T}{\rightarrow} W & & \color{red}{Z^*}\overset{U^*}{\rightarrow}W^* \\
{\tiny{UT}}\searrow~\downarrow {\tiny{U}}& & \color{red}{{\tiny{T^*U^*}}\searrow}~\downarrow {\tiny{T^*}} \\
~~~~~~~~~~Z & & ~~~~~~~~~~~~\color{red}{V^*}
\end{array}

Note:

\begin{array}{rcl}
V^*&=&\{\varphi_V:V\rightarrow F, \text{$\varphi_V$ linear}\} \\ \\
W^*&=&\{\varphi_W:W\rightarrow F, \text{$\varphi_W$ linear}\} \\ \\
Z^*&=&\{\varphi_Z:Z\rightarrow F, \text{$\varphi_Z$ linear}\}
\end{array}

Thus, we have that

\begin{eqnarray}
(UT)^*(h)=h(UT),~h\in Z^*
\end{eqnarray}

by the definition of dual map (tranpsose) and

\begin{eqnarray}
h(UT)=(hU)T
\end{eqnarray}

by the associativity of transformations. Now, $hU$ is characterized by the map

\begin{eqnarray}
W\overset{U}{\rightarrow}Z~~ \\
{\tiny{hU}}\searrow~\downarrow {\tiny{h}} \\
F~~,
\end{eqnarray}

---

so $hU\in W^*$, and it is clear then that

\begin{eqnarray}
(hU)T=T^*(hU),
\end{eqnarray}

but $hU=U^*h$, or simply $U^{*}$, because $h$ itself is an element of $Z^*$ for which $U^*$ maps to $W^*$.

---

Hence, $(UT)^*=T^*U^*$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: I'm unclear, however, between the lines.